# Create an MS Teams app that is always added to all meetings

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to create an app for **Microsoft Teams** that, after installed and approved by the user, is always 'added' to all meetings and group conversations. Is that possible? The documentation from Microsoft is not clear about it.

The app is meant to get notifications from the meeting - someone has joined, recording has started, meeting has ended, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, We are adding the custom teams app manually.

Ref doc :-https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/main/msteams-platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/enable-and-configure-your-app-for-teams-meetings.md

We do not have API to add the app to all meetings.
At the moment, it has to be a two step process. First, create the meeting using Graph and then add the app to the meeting using Graph.

Could you please raise a user voice here for new requirement:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new